# rails nested form not permitting a parameter that it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I can't figure out why this nested form is not working.  Skill belongs_to Profile and profile has_many skills.  For some reason, the sever logs show the following error when the form is submitted:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gdskfkjsdflkdjshgk",
 "profile"=>{"skill"=>{"label"=>"PHP"}}, "commit"=>"ADD +", "id"=>"134"}

Unpermitted parameters: skill
```

Here is the form code:

```
<%= form_for @profile  do |f| %>            
        <%= f.fields_for :skill do |builder| %>
               <%= builder.select :label, @crafts.collect {|craft| craft.label},
                  {include_blank: true} %>
        <% end %>   

        <%= f.submit "ADD +", :id => "clickme", :class => 'button button-add' %>
<% end %>
```

Here are the strong parameters in the profiles controller:

```
params.require(:profile).permit( skill_attributes: [:label, :id])
```

Here is the edit controller for the form action:

```
def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile 
    @skill = Skill.new  #field for new skill
end
```

Here is the relevant part of the profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :skills
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills,  :allow_destroy => true
end
```

The reason I use "skill_attributes" and "f.fields_for :skill" is because I only want one skill to be created/updated at a time and using the plural puts two inputs on the page.

Comment: What's the latest on this?

Comment: If the OP is not going to update with whether or not any of the provided solutions are helpful, I'll feel compelled to downvote this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your form (skills) doesn't match with what is expected for accepts_nested_attributes (skills_attributes).  You can use this I think:

```
= fields_for "profile[skills_attributes]" do |builder|
```